# Turn off folder browsing with IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have a hosted web site built using ASP.Net. I was working on an update and wanted to install it in a sub folder of the domain to test it. I published it using VS 2010, but the site would not run. I contacted the vendor and they made some changes. Although the site run you must type in the full path to `default.aspx` to view the main page. I was expecting that typing the path in to the browser will find and load `default.aspx`; instead it shows the folder contents in the browser window.

I contacted the vendor again and they said I must use IIS 7 or above to turn off folder browsing myself or they could do it for me for one-time fee of $95. I downloaded IIS and logged in to my domain, but I don't see the folder where the new site is. If fact, I don't see any of my folders or files. I don't see a WWWRoot. I'm not really sure what I'm looking at.

How do I find the folder in IIS? If I can find it I see the option to turn off folder browsing.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

Enable or Disable Directory Browsing in IIS 7

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

```
Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).

In Features View, double-click Directory Browsing.

In the Actions pane, click Enable if the Directory Browsing feature is disabled and you want to enable it. Or, click Disable if the Directory Browsing feature is enabled and you want to disable it.
```

Comment: "Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage". I don't see the level I want to manage. As I said, I don't see any of my folders or files. There are a lot of folders and files, but not mine. My credentials work so I seem to be at my domain.

Comment: I'm not sure.  You should have the computer name at the root, then websites folder underneath then the actual websites and under those you'll have web applications (potentially).

Comment: I counted 111 folders under the root. None look at all like the folders on my site. I dread going back to Web.com, but I guess I will have to. Thanks.