# I don't see web site folders when viewing site in IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

[image]I asked this question yesterday ([Turn off folder browsing with IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503876/turn-off-folder-browsing-with-iis)), but I asked it wrong, so I'm trying again. When I log on to my site using IIS I don't see any folders or files relating to my site. I see over 100 folders off the root, but none of them are my folders that I created. The first three are 0409, 1033, AdvancedInstallers.

Why don't I see the folders and files from my site.

Greg

Comment: Unclear what you are really asking. What do you mean "log on to my site using IIS"? Guessing from your earlier question, this sounds like you need to figure things out with your hosting provider (how they setup sites, etc).

Comment: By "log on to my site using IIS", I mean I open up IIS and type in my domain name. I then supply username and password. IIS then lists dozens of folders, none of which are folders for my site. I submitted a support ticket with my hosting provider. Their response: "We deal just with general hosting support unfortunately this is not a feature that we support directly which you would need to research"

Comment: You're probably asking the wrong question. Hosting providers typically have instructions on where/what folders to put your files in. If you have a dedicated box where you control everything, then as the term implies, you can do whatever you want using `IIS Manager` and this question is moot. The way you describe your process doesn't sound like IIS Manager, more like some interface your hosting providers gives you (so ask them questions along that line).

Comment: Nope, I downloaded IIS manager from MS. Help/About says "Internet Information Services (Version 8.5.9600.16384) This product is licensed under the Microsoft License Terms to: blah, blah, blah". I do not have a dedicated box. When I publish from Visual Studio i do it via FTP. Pointing IIS to the ftp URL lists the same folders.

Comment: Ok, sounds like they allow IIS Remote Mgmt. Why don't you put up a screenshot (and remove/blur out anything sensitive). IMHO though, your hosting provider should ideally be your first line for this...

Comment: Right-click and View Image in New Tab for a better view. There are 111 folders. I have expanded all ( I think) some expand like the Windows Registry, and can't find anything that looks like my site. I have ask the vendor again for help. Their support ticket usually takes weeks to respond.

Comment: It looks like your physical path for that site is pointing to a system folder. You probably need to have the root folder point to a more suitable location.

Comment: Whoa - I think if you sent this screenshot to your provider, they (should) escalate it :) As the previous comment suggests, if that is in fact a _system_ folder, remotely exposed via IIS...whatever the reason for it is, and it's a _shared_ system (not dedicated, it's not "your" own box), and also accessible via FTP (?)...holy.....

Comment: Interesting. Maybe this will get their attention. Little else seems to unless it is a basic question about their web site builder, which I don't use. If they don't respond, maybe I'll try and get their attention by deleting a few folders :-)